# sprintf to make a bunch of file names

Tags: c, printf

I'm trying to use sprintf to make a bunch of strings that represent file names.  The files will be named 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...  However when I do this I get some weird errors.  The for loop only prints out the first round.  The output is shown here: str: 1.xlxs  i: 7567468

```
char str[3];
int i;

for(i = 0; i < FILES; i++){
    sprintf(str, "%d%s", i+1, ".xlxs");
printf("str: %s\n", str);
    printf("i: %i\n", i);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `str[3]` buffer is too small to hold the data (`"1.xlxs"`). It should be at least `str[7]` to hold the string and a null byte.

If the buffer is too small, you'll get a buffer overflow:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_buffer_overflow

Answer (score 1):

You reserved too little space in `str`. You need one character for `i`, 5 for the extension `".xlxs"` and yet another for the trailing `\0`, so declare `str` like:

```
char str[7];
```

to fit in your string. Because, if the buffer is too small, `printf` can't find `\0` and will print any data it finds until there is a `\0`.

Answer (score 1):

Make this modification , and you are good to go.

```
#define FILES 3   

char str[FILES][7];
int i;

for(i = 0; i < FILES; i++)
{
    sprintf(str[i], "%d%s", i+1, ".xlxs");
    printf("str: %s\n", str[i]);
    printf("i: %i\n", i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `str` buffer is only 3 characters long, but the string you're trying to put into it is far larger.  It works because you happen to be able to write off the end of array in this instance without anything bad happening.

Answer (score 0):

In your case it would be safer to use this:

```
snprintf(str, sizeof(str), "%d%s", i+1, ".xlxs");
```

This will make sure you don't go over the limits of your character array.

Specifically, you need at least `char[7]` to hold `"1.xlxs\0"`.